# When to use auto_created attribute of field in django?

Tags: django-models, django-orm

Could you please give me a real example when should I use auto_created attribute in definitions of django model fields? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.auto_created ? Which kind of problems could be solved by using this flag?

Comment: I am also looking for this, surprisingly, i couldn't find any example.

Answer (score 1):

Found one example here. http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/74720/django.db.migrations.CreateModel

Here is my wild guess: it is designed for Django primary key implementation, that is, you'd better do not use it unless you are developing Django itself.

```
fields=[
    ('pony_ptr', models.OneToOneField(
        auto_created=True,
        primary_key=True,
        to_field='id',
        serialize=False,
        to='Pony',
    )),
    "cuteness", models.IntegerField(default=1)),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to use it (at least to create fields with such attribute). auto_created=True means that field is created implicitly (`id` field which is automatically created for your model if you don't specify different primary key).